# Store Objects in Array difference in PHP 4 and 5

Tags: php, arrays, php4

I had similar problem in the post here:
[Storing objects in an array with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064854/storing-objects-in-an-array-with-php)

The test code is attached below.

The interesting thing is when I run the same code in PHP 4.3.9, and it outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => timitem Object
        (
            [t1] => a
            [t2] => a
        )

    [1] => timitem Object
        (
            [t1] => b
            [t2] => b
        )

    [2] => timitem Object
        (
            [t1] => c
            [t2] => c
        )

)
```

When I run it in PHP 5, and it outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => timItem Object
        (
            [t1] => c
            [t2] => c
        )

    [1] => timItem Object
        (
            [t1] => c
            [t2] => c
        )

    [2] => timItem Object
        (
            [t1] => c
            [t2] => c
        )

)
```

Can anyone point me a direction where I can find the related documentation regarding this changes in PHP 4 and 5?

Actually I am wondering if there is a switch I can turn off in PHP5 to do the same in PHP4. (I have a lot of this kind of code in an old project).

The test code is:

```
    <?php

class timItem{
  var $t1;
  var $t2;
  function timItem(){
  }
  function setItem($t1, $t2){
    $this->t1 = $t1;
    $this->t2 = $t2;
  }
} 

$arr = Array();

$item = new timItem();
$item->setItem("a","a");
$arr[] = $item;
$item->setItem("b","b");
$arr[] = $item;
$item->setItem("c","c");
$arr[] = $item;

print_r($arr);

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP4, `$arr[] = $item` adds a copy of `$item` to `$arr`. In PHP5, a reference to `$item` is added to `$arr`.

From [PHP: Assignment Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php):

> Note that the assignment copies the original variable to the new one (assignment by value), so changes to one will not affect the other. ...
>
> An exception to the usual assignment by value behaviour within PHP occurs with objects, which are assigned by reference in PHP 5.

Comment: That explained everything. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because PHP5 is said to be object oriented, you should change your assignments into something like this:

`$arr[] = clone $item`.

I don't think, that you can force PHP5 to act in a non-object-oriented way.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is not in the arrays as such, but in the way PHP handles objects.  PHP 4 would pretty much always make a copy of an item when you assigned a variable, but PHP 5 works more like Java, C# etc where assignment makes a reference.

Have a look at http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php for more info.